# Увеличение длины на элемента на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Пишу змейку на `Javascript`. Нужно чтобы после прохождения через ячейку где находится еда длина змеи увеличивалась. Каким образом это можно реализовать? Вот код:

```js
const KEY_LEFT = 37;
const KEY_UP = 38;
const KEY_RIGHT = 39;
const KEY_DOWN = 40
var vendors = ["webkit", "moz", "o", "ms"];
for (var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; x++) {
  window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + "RequestAnimationFrame"];
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + "CancelAnimationFrame"] ||
    window[vendors[x] + "CancelRequestAnimationFrame"];
}
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var rows = '';
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
  rows += '<tr class="row" + i';
  for (var j = 0; j <= 25; j++) {
    rows += '<td></td>';
  }
  rows += '</tr>';
}
table.innerHTML = rows;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;

function move(i, j) {
  var old = document.querySelector("td.red");
  //console.log(i, j);
  if (old)
    old.classList.remove("red");
  table.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add("red");
}
addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == KEY_UP) { // up
    i--;
    if (i < 0)
      i = table.rows.length - 1;
  } else if (event.keyCode == KEY_DOWN) { // down
    i++;
    if (i >= table.rows.length)
      i = 0;
  } else if (event.keyCode == KEY_RIGHT) { // right
    j++;
    if (j >= table.rows[0].cells.length)
      j = 0;
  } else if (event.keyCode == KEY_LEFT) { // left
    j--;
    if (j < 0)
      j = table.rows[0].cells.length - 1;
  }
  move(i, j);
});
move(i, j);

function randomFood(i, j) {
  var food = document.querySelector("td.green");
  if (food)
    food.classList.remove("green");
  table.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add("green");
}
randomFood(5, 8);
```

```css
#table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td.red {
  background: red;
}

td.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr class="row">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос по логике то вот несколько советов.

1. Сохранить координаты из ф-ии randomFood() в отдельные переменные
2. При каждом движении сравнивать координаты текущей клетки с координатами из ф-ии randomFood()
3. Для того что бы змейка увеличивалась координаты текущей клетки лучше записывать в массив массивов и менять класс на "red" у всех ячеек таблицы с координатами из этого массива
4. При поедании просто добавлять координаты но не удалять.
5. При движении добавляя координаты новой клетки в начало(например) массива и удаляя последние.
6. При каждом движении сравнивать новые координаты с имеющимися в массиве что бы предотвратить прохождение через себя.

если в процессе реализации возникнут вопросы по коду пиши.